# Determine if the amplitude of the sinusoidal function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I know the answer is -10 because at t=0, it is 10 and the midline is 20, and therefore the amplitude is 10, but I couldnt understand the explanation or rationale behind the graph.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone elaborate the sentence boxed up in red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify the explanation, let's consider the function $f(t)=a\cos(bt)$.

---

**Case 1:** $a>0$, $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let's consider the specific case where $a=1$ and $b=1$. Here, I've plotted the graph for you:

[image]

Here, note where the graph starts where $t=0$: $\cos{t}=1$. At $t=0$, that is the **maximum value** of $\cos{t}$. This also applies for the general case, where $a>0$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$ for $f(t)=a\cos(bt)$: there is always a maximum at $t=0$. Hence, your ferris wheel would have to initially be at its highest point for Case 1 to be true.

---

**Case 2:** $a<0$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, let's let $a$ be negative and $b$ be a real number. Here, I choose $a=-1$ and $b=1$ for simplicity:

[image]

When $t=0$, $\cos{t}=-1$ in this case. It is the **minimum value** of $-\cos{t}$ at that time. Similarly, this also applies generally for $f(t)$ where $a<0$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, your ferris wheel would have to initially be at its lowest point for Case 2 to be true.

---

Now, notice for your example notice that:

> At $t=0$, when she starts moving, she is at a height $10 \text{ m}$ off the ground, which is **as low as she goes**. After $20\pi$ seconds, she reaches her maximum height of $30 \text{ m}$.

The function $H(t)$ here **starts from a minimum at $t=0$ and is followed by a maximum point**. Therefore, $a<0$.

Comment: Thanks for the graph. Can I summarise it as: cos(0) will always return 1, therefore, if the starting value is below the mid-line, the amplitude shall be negative and vice versa. Is there any better explanation?

Comment: Everything you've said is valid, as long as you are considering functions in the form $H(t)=a\cos(bt)+d$. For your case, I would summarize it as: $$ $$ $a>0$: Initial maximum point followed by a minimum point where $t\in [0,\infty)$. $$ $$ $a<0$: Initial minimum point followed by a maximum where $t\in [0,\infty)$.